# styles.xml with android version qualifier cause app crash

Tags: android, android-resources

My app use a different style for minimum version of Android:
My app use a minimum version:   API 9  Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)

I use Version qualifier for assign a different style to every Android version:

My styles file from `values/style.xml` is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme">

</style>
```

My styles file from `values-v11/styles.xml` (if device is Android 3.0 or later):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

</style>
```

My styles file from `values-v14/styles.xml` (if device is Android 4.0 or later):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault">

</style>
```

The following .xml is only a fragment of `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

---

My issue is: When the app runs in my phone, the app crashes unexpectedly, I know that my issue is in the use of version qualifiers.

Comment: pls post your exception stacktrace

Comment: I only add styles.xml with folder as `values-v11`

Comment: Without you posting the exception log, I'd just make a guess: your folder should be named like `values-v11` or `values-v21`, not `values-11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Android 2.3 for more compatibility.
On Android Studio, the activities for minimum versions (like Android 2.3 Gingerbread or earlier) are created automatically with the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

The `ActionBarActivity` isn't compatible with styles different to `AppCompat`

Try to convert from `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```